# How to determine which database table columns need to be updated from modified struct?

Tags: go

The problem that I am facing is more of a code design rather than specifically go related. I am building a simple CRUD application and everything seems to go nice and easy except the updating part: I have a struct type as simple as:

```golang
type User struct {
   ID string
   Name string
   Password string
}
```

and an interface for data storage layer:

```golang
type Store interface {
    ...
    Update(user *User) error
    ...
}
```

The problem is that with most database drivers you can't just pass the whole struct instance and hope the their system knows which fields were modified, the whole document/row gets replaced. How should I track which fields were modified (so that I could update them in the storage layer accordingly)? Maybe pass all the fields I would like to modify to the Update function as a map of interface{}?

Comment: Depending on your struct it may be more expensive to find out what changed than to just write the whole record

Comment: Check out [gorm](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm) although it also comes with its own limitations/problems.

Comment: I just write my update func to update everything except the password. In the handler I get the record, scan row into struct, marshal request JSON into that struct (overwriting DB values with those from request body if present) then pass struct to update method to save..

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to achieve that. For example you can use setters to change the values.So you can keep track of updated fields.
like so :

```
type User struct {
   ID string
   Name string
   Password string
   updateFields map[string]bool
}

func (u *User) SetName(name string) {
   u.Name = name
   updateFields["name"] = true
}
```

You can use more automated way by reflection.